# Google Places show Error while using proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard, google-places-autocomplete

After migrating to new google place library in android every thing is working fine as expected without proguard. But while enabling the proguard I got the following error

```
com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.hg: can't find referenced class com.google.j2objc.annotations.RetainedWith
```

In gradle for google places I used

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

For Similar question Some one has added the following to resolve the issue but for me its still not working

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
 static final long serialVersionUID;
 private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
 !static !transient <fields>;
 !private <fields>;
 !private <methods>;
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
 java.lang.Object writeReplace();
 java.lang.Object readResolve();
 }
```

But still same error. How can I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a stab in the dark, but I would try this:

```
-keep public class com.google.j2objc.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.**
```

Answer (score 0):

use google places version 1.0.0 instead of 1.1.0